# OpenGL: cylinder misshaped after turning it 90 degree

Tags: c++, opengl, glut, freeglut

I and my college project partner are doing this project. We write this in c++ and OpenGL 2.1 with the freeglut.lib We turned the cylinder to lay down on the ground by 90 degrees. Now the cylinder is oddly [misshaped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bm12y.png). How can we fix the misshape? Is this a perspective thing? We wanted to use the cylinder later as wheels for a car which we should animate driving in a circle track. Right now the wheels on the [car](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLhDS.png) are only 2D circles.

```
void draw_cylinder(GLfloat radius,
    GLfloat height,
    GLubyte R,
    GLubyte G,
    GLubyte B)
{
    GLfloat x = 0.0;
    GLfloat y = 0.0;
    GLfloat angle = 0.0;
    GLfloat angle_stepsize = 0.1;

    /** Draw the tube */
    glColor3ub(R - 40, G - 40, B - 40);
    glBegin(GL_QUAD_STRIP);
    angle = 0.0;
    while (angle < 2 * PI) {
        x = radius * cos(angle);
        y = radius * sin(angle);
        glVertex3f(x, y, height);
        glVertex3f(x, y, 0.0);
        angle = angle + angle_stepsize;
    }
    glVertex3f(radius, 0.0, height);
    glVertex3f(radius, 0.0, 0.0);
    glEnd();

    /** Draw the circle on top and bottom of cylinder */
    glColor3ub(R, G, B);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    angle = 0.0;
    while (angle < 2 * PI) {
        x = radius * cos(angle);
        y = radius * sin(angle);
        glVertex3f(x, y, height);
        angle = angle + angle_stepsize;
    }
    glVertex3f(radius, 0.0, height);
    glEnd();
}

void display(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glTranslatef(0.0, -0.4, -3.0);
    //glRotatef(-40, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glRotatef(-200, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);

    draw_cylinder(0.3, 0.5, 255, 160, 100);

    glFlush();
}

void reshape(int width, int height)
{
    if (width == 0 || height == 0) return;

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(40.0, (GLdouble)width / (GLdouble)height,
        0.5, 20.0);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    /** Initialize glut */
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(640, 480);
    glutCreateWindow("Create Cylinder");
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);

    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Looks for me as if you would be turning the cylinder by -200 degrees, not 90. If I'm not mistaken, you also do not use depth testing, which causes the further away faces to be drawn over the nearer face.

Comment: I first tried with 90, but somehow it changed nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to enable the [Depth Test](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Depth_Test):

```cpp
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
```

and clear the depth buffer as well

```cpp
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```

Example:

[image]

```cpp
float angle = 0.0f;
void display(void)
{
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glTranslatef(0.0, -0.4, -3.0);
    glRotatef(angle, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    angle += 0.1f;
    glRotatef(-200, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);

    draw_cylinder(0.3, 0.5, 255, 160, 100);

    glFlush();
    glutPostRedisplay();
}
```